# Are these symbols really used in "Set Theory"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am confused. Please, help me!

I am studying "Set Theory" and I am really not trusting in the quality of the material provided and since I am not a math expert I decided to ask in order to clear any doubts lest I learn something the wrong way.

Are the symbols below REALLY used in set theory:

[image]

Above is an IMAGE to make sure you are seeing the same thing as I am (I know fonts may be decoded incorrectly).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's an encoding error. Surely, you would know what the symbol for "element of" is, from the top of your head ...

Comment: Pleas don't use pictures, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The picture has the wrong encoding. Certainly you know that $\emptyset$ is the empty set.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. Now I know the symbols are indeed incorrect (fortunately).

Comment: I asked because I am no expert. And I thought those characters could have been an alternative way of representing operations. Now, I know they are not.

Comment: Rest assured that **is** infact an encoding error.

Comment: I don't see why this got a downvote. The OP was presented with a purported list of symbols, was confused by them, and asked about their validity. That seems pretty appropriate to me. (Additional context doesn't seem to be an issue since the question is whether these symbols are used *elsewhere.*)

Comment: This being said it kinda makes me want to write an article with those symbols now.

Comment: You may want to read another set of notes first, e.g. [these](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/43812/materials). And of course P. Halmos' _Naive Set Theory_ is an excellent source (if you have access to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have said, **no**, the symbols you're seeing are not the actual symbols - there's clearly been an encoding error.

For the record, the correct symbols are as follows:

- The emptyset is "$\emptyset$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\emptyset`).
- The elementhood relation is "$\in$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\in`).
- There is a bit of ambiguity around the "contained in" (or "subset of") relation. We basically have three relevant symbols: "$\subseteq$" ($\LaTeX$ code "`\subseteq`), "$\subset$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\subset`), and "$\subsetneq$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\subsetneq`). Generally the first is most common and refers to subsethood broadly, while the third refers exclusively to proper subsethood. The second is annoying: *usually* it refers to proper subsethood, but occasionally it's used for the broader notion of subsethood in general (Munrkes' topology book does this). My experience is that $\subset$ is largely avoided in more modern literature.
- The same ambiguity exists with respect to the "contains" (or "superset of") relation, the relevant symbols being "$\supseteq$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\supseteq`), "$\supset$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\supset`), and "$\supsetneq$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\supsetneq`).
- The negation of a relation *("not an element of," "not a subset of," etc.)* is gotten by putting a line through the relation itself, e.g. "$\not\in$" or "$\not\subseteq$" ($\LaTeX$ code `\not\[command]`).
- Intersection and union are "$\cup$" and "$\cap$" ($\LaTeX$ codes `\cup` and `\cap`) respectively.

---

Incidentally, if there's a symbol whose $\LaTeX$ code you don't know, try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: Use back ticks for code, `like this`.